# Using Jest/angular-testing-library to test eventEmitter subscription return

Tags: angular, jestjs, observable, eventemitter, angular-testing-library

I am coding with Angular and am attempting to write a test for the below function. We are not using the built in test and are using Jest with the angular-testing-library. When I run the test, I am not covering the

```ts
modalRef.componentInstance.emitService.subscribe((deleteConfirm: boolean) => {
      if(deleteConfirm) {
        this.deleteIndividualCertById(id);
      }
});
```

portion of the below function.
My question is: **How do I write the test to cover the subscription and missing branch that is in the if statement?**

[Screenshot of test coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYmfz.png)

The function requiring the test:

```ts
openDeleteModal(id: number) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DeleteConfirmComponent, {
      size: 'lg',
      backdrop: 'static',
      centered: true,
    });
    modalRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = "Are you sure you wish to delete this Certification?";
    modalRef.componentInstance.emitService.subscribe((deleteConfirm: boolean) => {
      if(deleteConfirm) {
        this.deleteIndividualCertById(id);
      }
    });
}
```

The modal is held in another component (DeleteConfirmComponent) to make it reusable. The `confirmDelete()` function is called by the confirm button on the modal. The code for the modal is:

```ts
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-confirm',
  templateUrl: './delete-confirm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-confirm.component.css']
})

export class DeleteConfirmComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  @Input() confirmMessage: any;
  @Output() emitService = new EventEmitter();


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log();
  }

  confirmDelete(){
    this.emitService?.next(true);
    this.activeModal?.close('Close click');
  }

}
```

The fault is with me not really understanding how to capture the eventEmitter that sets the `deleteConfirm` boolean and then verify it moves on to the `deleteIndividualCertById(id)` function in the if statement.

I have tried a bunch of different things after spending a few days searching the internet and sites like Stack Overflow.

```ts
it('#openDeleteModal should call #deleteIndividualCertById when confirm is selected', async () => {
    const mockId = 123;
    const mockModalRef = {
      componentInstance: {
        confirmMessage: '',
        emitService: {
          subscribe: jest.fn(),
          next: jest.fn(),
          close: jest.fn()
        }
      },
      result: Promise.resolve(true)
    };
    const mockModalService = {
      open: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockModalRef),
      close: jest.fn()
    };

    const component = await render(CertificationsComponent, {
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, NgbPaginationModule, NgbModalModule],
      componentProviders: [
        { provide: NgbModal, useValue: mockModalService },
        { provide: NgbModalRef, useValue: mockModalRef },
        {provide: NgbActiveModal, useValue: NgbActiveModal}
      ]
    });
    const componentInstance = component.fixture.componentInstance;
    jest.spyOn(componentInstance, 'deleteIndividualCertById');

    componentInstance.openDeleteModal(mockId);
    expect(mockModalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DeleteConfirmComponent, {
      size: 'lg',
      backdrop: 'static',
      centered: true,
    });
    
    mockModalService.close();
    expect(mockModalService.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
    const deleteConfirm = true;
    console.log('LOG MSG: ', deleteConfirm);
    if(deleteConfirm) {
      componentInstance.deleteIndividualCertById(mockId);
      expect(componentInstance.deleteIndividualCertById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockId);
    }
    
  });
```

Here I have a simpler version of the modal mock that I haven't yet worked on targeting the missing branch.

```ts
test('Should #openDeleteModal with #id of selected certification', async () => {
    const component = await render(CertificationsComponent, {
      declarations: [CertificationsComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, NgbPaginationModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CertificationApiService,
          useValue: MockIndividualsApiService,
        },
      ],
    });
    expect(component);
    const componentInstance = component.fixture.componentInstance;
    let mockId = 1;
    componentInstance.openDeleteModal(mockId);
    const modal = mockModalService.open();
    expect(modal).toEqual({ ...mockReturn });
    });
```

I would appreciate some guidance here and as a side note, if you have any good references for Angular testing with Jest and the testing-library that I may have missed in my searching, please list them!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import { openDeleteModal } from './src/yourmodule';
import { DeleteConfirmComponent } from '../components/delete-confirm.component';

describe('openDeleteModal', () => {
    // Mock the ModalService
    const mockModalService = {
        open: jest.fn()
    };

    let modalRef;
    beforeEach(() => {
        modalRef = {
            componentInstance: {
                emitService: jest.fn()
            }
        }
        mockModalService.open.mockReturnValue(modalRef);
    });

    it('should set the correct message and size when calling open', () => {
        openDeleteModal(1, mockModalService);
        expect(mockModalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DeleteConfirmComponent, {
            size: 'lg',
            backdrop: 'static',
            centered: true
        });
        expect(modalRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage).toBe('Are you sure you wish to delete this Certification?');
    });

    it('should call deleteIndividualCertById when emitService is called with true', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(openDeleteModal, 'deleteIndividualCertById');
        openDeleteModal(1, mockModalService);
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        modalRef.componentInstance.emitService.mock.calls[0][0](true);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    });
});
```